# Adding item to inventory but is still clear (Bukkit/Spigot)

Tags: java, bukkit

I am coding a plugin for a friend and I'm coming across a problem. When  I add items to an inventory, they don't appear when a player runs the /kits command. Here is my code:

```java
public void createInv() {
        inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, this.getConfig().getInt("slots"), ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', this.getConfig().getString("header")));
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.matchMaterial(this.getConfig().getString("kits.1.icon")));
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        List<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String key : this.getConfig().getStringList("kits")) {
            lore.clear();
            item.setType(Material.matchMaterial(this.getConfig().getString("kits."+key+".icon")));
            lore.add(this.getConfig().getString("kits."+key+".lore"));
            meta.setLore(lore);
            meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', this.getConfig().getString("kits."+key+".name")));
            item.setItemMeta(meta);
            inv.setItem(this.getConfig().getInt("kits."+key+".slot"), item);
            
        }
    }
```

Here is my onCommand:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("kits")) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage("You cannot use this command!");
                return true;
            }
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            player.openInventory(inv);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I've gone through so many forums and haven't yet found a fix, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Also, this is Spigot 1.16.1

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, please update the question with the stack trace. Is `createInv` in the same class as your onCommand? If so, where does `createInv` get called?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Inventory getInventory() {
                Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, this.getConfig().getInt("slots"), ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', this.getConfig().getString("header")));

                for (String key : this.getConfig().getStringList("kits")) { //maybe this returns nothing?
                        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.matchMaterial(this.getConfig().getString("kits.1.icon")));
                        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
                        List<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
                        
                        lore.clear(); //??? it´s a empty list
                        item.setType(Material.matchMaterial(this.getConfig().getString("kits."+key+".icon")));
                        lore.add(this.getConfig().getString("kits."+key+".lore"));
                        meta.setLore(lore);
                        meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', this.getConfig().getString("kits."+key+".name")));
                        item.setItemMeta(meta);
                        inv.setItem(this.getConfig().getInt("kits."+key+".slot"), item);
                        
                }
                return inv;
        }

         p.openInventory(getInventory()); //later
```